# how to call procedure in procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have one procedure name Randomoutlet and i want to call that procedure via other procedure as code below

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MainSchedule] 
as
begin
DECLARE @sup table (supervisorId int)

INSERT INTO @sup SELECT DISTINCT SupervisorId  FROM CallPlan .dbo .CallPlanSchedule  WHERE MONTH (scheduledate)= MONTH (GETDATE ()) and YEAR (ScheduleDate )= YEAR(GETDATE())

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM @sup
DECLARE @suptem int 
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @suptem

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN       
    EXEC [dbo].[randomOutlet] @suptem
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @suptem        
END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR      
end
```

when i save MainSchedule it's show message "The module 'MainSchedule' depends on the missing object 'dbo.randomOutlet'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
"

and when i run this procedure it's appear error "Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure MainSchedule, Line 15
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.randomOutlet'."

please help me solve this problem thank in advance

Comment: What this procedure [dbo].[randomOutlet] returns ?? is it return a single integer or a table ?? if integer only better to use a functoin

Comment: it doesn't return any value. it's just have insert statement in that procedure

Comment: Your error means that the procedure dbo.randomOutlet does not exist on the same server & database as MainSchedule.  I know you think it does.  But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and got everything running fine.

```
CREATE procedure CALL_PROC --'abc'
@var varchar(100)
as
begin
declare @sup table (item int)
insert into @sup select 1 union select 2

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM @sup
DECLARE @var1 int 
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @var1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN       
    EXEC dbo.call_me @var1
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @var1        
END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR 
end
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CALL_ME]
@VAR VARCHAR(100)
AS
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null
begin
insert into #temp select @VAR
end
else
select @var value into #temp
select * from #temp
go
```

Please check if you have created the objects on the same DB or not.

Comment: these two procedures is on the same DB. but when i run it's still error

Comment: Are you getting error after running the code in my answer?

Comment: i didn't run yr code because it's have different business logic. i have done a lot of thing in the inner procedure.